# How to fix the error with dev-server watch?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

There is the following project structure
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqyma.png)

I want the server to run the project from dist, but when changing to src, it was recompiled and everything was copied to dist.

My webpack.config.js.

```js
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/scripts/script.js',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          {
              from: './src/index.html',
              to: '../index.html'
          }
      ]),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '../styles/style.css'
      })
  ],
  module: {
      rules: [
          {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,    
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader'
              ]
          }
      ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'script.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/scripts')
  }
};
```

Content script.js

```js
import './../styles/style.scss';
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "landing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
  "build": "webpack"
},
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "import-glob": "^1.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.28.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

At the moment, when changing to src, compilation occurs, but these changes do not fall into the dist folder.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [watchContentBase](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-watchcontentbase) option:

```
devServer: {
       contentBase: './dist',
       watchContentBase: true,
  },
```

When you use dev-server your changes does not go to the dist folder. It is stored in a buffer. For more details see this good explanation: [Why webpack-dev-server Live-Reload Is Not Working](https://medium.com/code-oil/burning-questions-with-answers-to-why-webpack-dev-server-live-reload-does-not-work-6d6390277920)

Comment: Can you share a package.json file?

Comment: add to question